# Automatically updating a field after a manuall update in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has a bunch of columns, one of which is a 'last_update_time' column. Whenever I change the value of any of the other columns, I would like 'last_update_time' to automatically update to `SYSDATE`.

I know that you would usually use triggers for this kind of thing, but as far as I am aware it is not possible to have a trigger for a table mutate that same table.

What is the best way of implementing the functionallity described above?

Comment: I post an answer to your question. You can achieve this using trigger before update of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger before update of. You only need to specify the columns that might be updated in the clause before of

Take a look at this

```
SQL> create table testtrg ( c1 number, c2 date ) ;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger mytrig
before update of c1
on testtrg
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
declare
begin
   :new.c2  := sysdate;
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from testtrg;

no rows selected

SQL> insert into testtrg values ( 1 , sysdate - 360 );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from testtrg ;

        C1 C2
---------- ---------
         1 28-JUL-19

SQL> update testtrg set c1=2 ;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL>  select * from testtrg ;

        C1 C2
---------- ---------
         2 22-JUL-20

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. Does that mean if I specify a set of columns in the "before update of" , I can freely update other columns of that table that are not in the set?

Comment: the columns you specify in the clause before of are the ones that before any change on them, the column date will be updated automatically to sysdate. If you want to apply to only some columns, updates over the remaining will not have effect over the date column

Comment: `exception when others then raise` doesn't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, indeed it could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In my tables I like to keep track of when it was created in addition to when it was last modified. My triggers look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tnsnames.tns_server_override_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "TNSNAMES".tns_server_override
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :new.modified_dt   := SYSDATE;
    :new.modified_by   := SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'OS_USER' );

    CASE
       WHEN INSERTING
    THEN
        :new.created_dt   := :new.modified_dt;
        :new.created_by   := :new.modified_by;
    WHEN UPDATING
    THEN
        :new.created_dt   := :old.created_dt;
        :new.created_by   := :old.created_by;
    END CASE;
END;
```